# Fullcalendar How do I change date format to UK calendar format

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I'm using FullCalendar `v3.5.1` plugin which uses US calendar format by default. How could I change it to UK format `dd/mm/yyyy`.

```
$('#calender').fullCalendar({
header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
},
defaultView: 'basicWeek',
events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
   }
});
```

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/localization

Answer (score 1):

You want to set the locale as `'en-gb'` like as follows.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cyz6Lva3/) working. You also need to retrieve https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.0.0/locale-all.js

If you look at resources on the left you can see what libraries you need.

[image]

Below you can see the code you need.

```
...

$('#calender').fullCalendar({
   locale: 'en-gb',
   header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
    },
   defaultView: 'basicWeek',
   events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
   }
});
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier ON THIS LINE `import gbLocale from '@fullcalendar/core/locales/en-gb';
let `

Comment: are you using the `import` syntax? I guess you aren't running a server and it is just a static html page?

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` I am using it in my php website on xampp server.

Comment: Now the error gone, But its still giving the old date format , June 2020 in month view, week view (Jun 21 – 27, 2020) And in day view (June 21, 2020).

Comment: ok by adding locale-all.js its showing now as  22 – 28 Jun 2020, could you change the month to digits.